# Extracting State to Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So my question is, Why is the first version of code not working and the other one working?

> Just deleting the key element rather than keeping it

(I am a newbie on these so be gentle if this is a stupid question :)

## Version 1 (Not Works)

```
const ADD = 'ADD';

const addMessage = (message) => {
  return {type: ADD, text: message};
}

function messageReducer(state = [], action) {
  if(action.type == ADD){
    return [...state, action.text];
  }
  else{
    return state;
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(messageReducer);
```

## Version 2 (Works)

```
const ADD = 'ADD';

const addMessage = (message) => {
  return {type: ADD, message};
}

function messageReducer(state = [], action) {
  if(action.type == ADD){
    return [...state, action.message];
  }
  else{
    return state;
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(messageReducer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples above should actually work because both are valid. The only difference is that the message in the first example has been bound in an arbitrary parameter called text, but it is still properly extracted using action.text.

You can find a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-forked-ksz3b?file=/reducer.js

Comment: Then, I am guessing that this problem's source is a compiler that I am using.  Because seems totally fine as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try my best to tackle this, haven't worked with Redux in a bit.

Initially I would write your conditional statements with case/break (it's clearer to me, but a preference). It seems like you're trying to implement an array as the "state" in the reducer to leverage the ability to add information into an already existing pool.

To rewrite your code with switch statements and an object state variable declaration would look like this:

```
const ADD = 'ADD';

const addMessage = (message) => {
  return { type: ADD, text: message };
}

function messageReducer(state = {}, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD:
          return ...state, action.text;
        default:
          return state;

      }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(messageReducer);
```

I would then approach this by building an initial state with an array and destructuring that key out to add values into. So this could something like this:

```
const initialState = { msgArr: ['hello world'] }

const ADD = 'ADD';

const addMessage = (message) => {
  return { type: ADD, text: message };
}

function messageReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD:
          return ...state, [...state.msgArr, action.text];
        default:
          return state;

      }
}
```

I'm having a bit a bit of an issue linking my working codepen example, so feel free to test this out and see if this works. Hopefully I didn't miss the mark on your question. Best of luck!